# Android Market Link shows two options

Tags: android, hyperlink, google-play

I have the following working code:

```
startActivity(
    new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
        Uri.parse("http://market.android.com/details?id=me.cexi.accuapp")));
```

When the user clicks on the Action Button, they get the Complete action using dialog with the following:

```
Browser
Market
```

How do I limit the option to just the market?

Answer (score 5):

from [using intents to launch market app](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/publishing.html#marketintent)

use `market://details?id=<packagename>` instead of the `http://market.android.com/...` URL